# Does tilting the angle of the harmonica affect when overblowing?

Tags: harmonica

I just read a question about overblow on harmonica. One answer gave me the impression that the direction of the air stream should be directed at the bottom reed instead of the top reed. If that is the case, will adjusting the tilt of the harmonica aid in redirecting the air stream toward the bottom reed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might, but probably not.

I tried just now to hold an overblow while tilting the harmonica up and down; I got it from lying flat against my shin with my upper lip stretched over it (I felt like a tapir) to touching my nose (the latter an acrobatic feat which took me several minutes to nail). I used a Seydel Session Steal in A, and it worked for the hole 2 and hole 6 both.

What I meant (I suspect you are referring to my answer) isn't necessarily that the air needs to be actually redirected, but rather that imagining the air stream pointing downwards used to help me find the right mouth shape. It makes me raise the back of my tongue and general back area of my mouth, while lowering the front slightly. (I'll try to clarify the other answer too)

This said, I *do* understand the impulse to tilt the harp when doing difficult bends or overbends. I used to do it and I think I still do sometimes. The main effect of this, though, I think is to slightly change the length or volume of your mouth. With either side of your hand in contact with your face, pivoting around the point of contact, small precise movements are easier than it would be to simply move the harp in or out of your mouth. Thus you move one parameter away from the brain centre controlling your tongue, which is already overloaded trying to find the right shape. With practice, more of the things a beginner might do with her hands can be transferred to her mouth, but I see no drawback with keeping on using the hands for as long as one wishes.